# Can not restart the httpd because of the unknown syntax error

Tags: linux, centos, httpd

I can not restart the httpd:

```
[root@controller conf.d]# systemctl restart httpd
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And I see the logs:

```
[root@controller conf.d]# systemctl status httpd 
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-07-13 00:01:48 CST; 2min 5s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 18076 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 18074 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 18074 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 13 00:01:48 controller systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jul 13 00:01:48 controller httpd[18074]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 23 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/00-nova-placement-api.conf:
Jul 13 00:01:48 controller httpd[18074]: Illegal option
Jul 13 00:01:48 controller systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 13 00:01:48 controller kill[18076]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jul 13 00:01:48 controller systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 13 00:01:48 controller systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jul 13 00:01:48 controller systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jul 13 00:01:48 controller systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

You see this two line:

> Jul 13 00:01:48 controller httpd[18074]:AH00526: Syntax error on line 23 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/00-nova-placement-api.conf:
>   Jul 13 00:01:48 controller httpd[18074]: Illegal option

But in the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/00-nova-placement-api.conf` file:

```
  1 Listen 8778
  2 
  3 <VirtualHost *:8778>
  4 WSGIProcessGroup nova-placement-api
  5 WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  6 WSGIPassAuthorization On
  7 WSGIDaemonProcess nova-placement-api processes=3 threads=1 user=nova group=nova
  8 WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/bin/nova-placement-api
  9 <Directory "/">
 10   Order allow,deny
 11   Allow from all
 12   Require all granted
 13 </Directory>
 14 <IfVersion >= 2.4>
 15   ErrorLogFormat "%M"
 16 </IfVersion>
 17   ErrorLog /var/log/nova/nova-placement-api.log
 18 </VirtualHost>
 19 
 20 Alias /nova-placement-api /usr/bin/nova-placement-api
 21 <Location /nova-placement-api>
 22   SetHandler wsgi-script
 23   Options +ExecCGI
 24   WSGIProgressGroup nova-placement-api
 25   WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
 26   WSGIPassAuthorization On
 27 </Location>
~                                                                                                                                                                                  
~                                                                                                                                                                                  
~
```

The 23 line is correct, why there is error here?

---

**EDIT-1**

The authority is below:

```
[root@controller conf.d]# pwd
/etc/httpd/conf.d
[root@controller conf.d]# ll
total 24
-rw-r-----. 1 root root  698 Jul 13 00:07 00-nova-placement-api.conf
-rw-r-----. 1 root root  695 Jul 12 23:56 00-nova-placement-api.conf.bak
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2926 Nov 20  2015 autoindex.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Jul 12 23:56 cp
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  366 Nov 20  2015 README
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1252 Nov 20  2015 userdir.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  824 Nov 20  2015 welcome.conf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   38 Jul 12 15:27 wsgi-keystone.conf -> /usr/share/keystone/wsgi-keystone.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end I found the error is in the 24 line not 23.

So it is the system mistake:

```
24   WSGIProgressGroup nova-placement-api
```

should be:

```
24   WSGIProcessGroup nova-placement-api
```